# Add a Value parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, drop-down-menu

how to add a Value parameter for DropDownList list item in code (use C#/ASP.NET/SharePoint)?

Comment: If any answer can help you, please select an answer or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("item 1", "Item 1 Value"));
```

Please refer [here](http://programming.top54u.com/Samples/ASP-Net-cs/Standard-Server-Controls-2/DropDownList-Control-Items-Dynamically/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Value is a property on the ListItem class you can set it as any other property:

```
item.Value = "your value";
```